# 'google' is not defined on Vue.Js project with Google Maps

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-maps

I'm trying to create a google maps box without third party libraries on a Vue.js project working with typescript, but I'm having some headaches. In practice I ran the command from the official site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript "npm i -D @ types / google.maps", and I entered the code below but the problem "'google' is not defined" occurs. I don't know what the problem could be.

Here the code

```js
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    let map: google.maps.Map;
    const center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 30, lng: -110 };

    function initMap(): void {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
        center,
        zoom: 8,
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` after adding the types?

Comment: yep, but always the same mistake

Comment: I know is a lot of trouble, but if you can create a new project from scratch (so that no info you might want to not show gets open) and add the google libraries and code (so you have a skeleton proj with just the problem part), then you can host it on github or such and others can pull it and try to give you an answer to your problem.
Again I know it is a lot of trouble but you can definitely get a proper (and fast) answer like that.

Are you using Vue2 or Vue3?

Comment: vue.js 3 for accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are @types/google.maps and then there is the actual API which needs to be loaded.

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

mounted: function () {
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: "",
      version: "weekly",
      libraries: ["places"]
    });

    let map: google.maps.Map;
    const center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 30, lng: -110 };

    loader.load().then(() => { map = new 
       google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
        center,
        zoom: 8,
        });
     });
    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way you've used (and what is written in the google site) is if your project is pure typescript.

Since you are dealing with Vue I would recommend using the following library:
https://vue3-google-map.netlify.app/getting-started/#your-first-map

They have an example of usage there and I think you will have a better experience using it with Vue3 than trying to make it work.
(You can probably remove the google stuff you currently have installed in your `package.json`)